# Bayesian estimation with a mixture of deterministic and stochastic parameters?

Tags: signal-processing, estimation, parameter-estimation

I am stuck on how to properly handle a situation where some of the parameters that must be estimated have a known distribution and some do not.  That is without artificially making up some distribution for the deterministic parameters.

Is it possible to set up a minimum mean square error (MMSE) or maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimator with both deterministic and stochastic parameters?  Stochastic parameters have a known distribution, deterministic must be estimated with no prior knowledge.  For example,
$$\boldsymbol\theta=\left[\begin{matrix}a & b\end{matrix}\right]^T $$
$$\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}a+b+\nu_1 \\ ab+\nu_2\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $\boldsymbol\theta$ is the vector of parameters, $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector of measurements, $\nu_1\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_\nu^2\right)$, $\nu_2\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_\nu^2\right)$, and $b\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma_b^2\right)$ but no distribution is available for $a$.

I put together a MAP estimator for a different system with a mix of stochastic and deterministic parameters by leaving out any probability information for the deterministic ones
$$\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}=\arg \max_{\boldsymbol\theta} \ln\left[p(\mathbf{x}|\boldsymbol\theta)p(\theta_s)\right]$$
where $\theta_s$ was the one stochastic parameter.  The estimator seemed to work well but this seems like an iffy approach and I can't really justify it to myself now.

MMSE is even more of a problem since it needs
$$p(\boldsymbol\theta\vert\mathbf{x})=\frac{p(\mathbf{x}\vert\boldsymbol\theta)p(\boldsymbol\theta)}{\int p(\mathbf{x}\vert\boldsymbol\theta)p(\boldsymbol\theta) d\boldsymbol\theta}$$
and it seems really questionable to just replace $p(\mathbf{x}\vert\boldsymbol\theta)p(\boldsymbol\theta)$ with $p(\mathbf{x}\vert\boldsymbol\theta)p(\theta_s)$ and only integrate over $\theta_s$.

Comment: what you are doing works well since you are effectively finding the MAP estimate of $\theta$, modeling the prior distribution of its "deterministic" parameters as uniform (i.e., constant over their range) and independent of the (prior) distribution of the "stochastic" parameters. This is a quite common approach for such cases, where the "deterministic" parameter is assumed to be a random variable with a, so called, "non-informative" prior.

Comment: @Stelios Thank you.  Can you recommend any books that cover this?  I've not seen non-informative priors mentioned other than in some online course notes now that I'm doing a search.